# How to properly link ffmpeg project in eclipse linux

Tags: linux, eclipse, ffmpeg

I have a little test project on linux eclipse using ffmpeg.
It is oke to make it using command line

```
g++ -o m_vector -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include m_vector.cpp -lavformat -lavcodec -lavutil -lm -lz -lva -lpthread
```

but in eclipse while linking i get a big list of errors

```
/home/user/projects/ffmpeg/libavcodec/internal.h:194: undefined reference to `av_rescale_q'
/usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a(mpegvideo.o): In function `update_picture_tables':
/home/user/projects/ffmpeg/libavcodec/mpegvideo.c:663: undefined reference to `av_buffer_unref'
/home/user/projects/ffmpeg/libavcodec/mpegvideo.c:663: undefined reference to `av_buffer_ref'
/home/user/projects/ffmpeg/libavcodec/mpegvideo.c:664: undefined reference to `av_buffer_unref'
/home/user/projects/ffmpeg/libavcodec/mpegvideo.c:664: undefined reference to `av_buffer_ref'
/home/user/projects/ffmpeg/libavcodec/mpegvideo.c:665: undefined reference to `av_buffer_unref'
/home/user/projects/ffmpeg/libavcodec/mpegvideo.c:665: undefined reference to `av_buffer_ref'
```

and so on

I've aded the needed libs in project and i use "extern c". My project knows also about needed includes. Digging internet did not give the answer.

Comment: I also took new ffmpeg from git repo and make install it manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swap the order of the libraries you're linking to, one depends on the other. The one that is depended on the most must be last, in this case libavutil.

Answer (score 0):

The libraries will be searched in path_to_gcc/usr/lib. Hopefully you bmay not having the libraries there.Add `-L$path-to-libraries`

Comment: ffmpeg files have undefined reference while linking. So i added -  L\usr\local\lib where the ffmpeg libs live , and nothing changed

Comment: Consider exporting the path to a variable and use it with `-L`(seems funny rit, have a try)

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu different Windows OS.

Ubuntu sort lib, so you can add lib like this:

`-lavdevice -lavformat -lavcodec -lavutil -lswscale -lavfilter -lpthread -lz -lm -lswresample`

After add finish. If you have error: `undefined reference to vaCreateBuffer...` then you should rebuild ffmpeg and disable `-lva` lib.

Example: You build in: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu

Replace lines PATH to:

`PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH" PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$HOME/ffmpeg_build/lib/pkgconfig"`

`./configure \`
 
`--prefix="$HOME/ffmpeg_build" \`
 
`--pkg-config-flags="--static" \`
 
`--extra-cflags="-I$HOME/ffmpeg_build/include" \`
 
`--extra-ldflags="-L$HOME/ffmpeg_build/lib" \`
 
`--bindir="$HOME/bin" \`
 
`--disable-vaapi`

 I don't build libx264, libx265, libfdk-aac..... b/c I don't need. If you need, you can build.

Line code: `--disable-vaapi` is disable `-lva` lib.